# Как две переменные поменять местами на асемблере?

Tags: переменные, ассемблер

как две переменные поменять местами на асемблере?

Comment: Код в студию. Телепаты в отпуске.

Comment: _Переменные_ поменять местами нельзя никак. Вот их _значения_ можно (если переменные одного размера, конечно).

Comment: @VladD не понял. Предоставьте код, и я с помощью vim поменяю Ваши переменные местами.

Comment: @alexlz: На уровне исходника — можно, но не на уровне скомпилированного-и-запущенного кода изнутри этого самого кода.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Допустим Вы задали вопрос связанный с архитектурой Intel x86-64 совместимого кода.

Тогда, команды:

- НЕ возможно! Переместить значение одной ячейки памяти в другую ячейку.
- Возможно! Положить значение одной ячейки в стек или регистр, а затем достать из стека  или положить из регистра в другую ячейку.

Первый вариант:

```
push eax
mov eax, dword ptr[ variable1-address ]
mov dword ptr[variable2-address], eax
pop eax
```

Второй вариант:

```
push dword ptr[variable1-address]
pop dword ptr[variable2-address]
```

Рекомендую использовать первый,т.к. он более привычный для программеров пишущих на столь низкоуровневом языке.

Comment: мне как раз интересно было узнать возможно ли обменять значения без использования дополнительной памяти. однако чуда не случилось. большое вам спасибо

Comment: @perfect регистр A/AX/EAX использовать разрешается? Если да -- то три XOR. Ну или тот же XCHG...

Comment: Ну можно не только с XOR , но и с SUB или ADD. Но за этот трюк прибить можно любого кто написал в проект. Пусть такое творчество будет в домашних проектах не вылезающее за пределы компьютеров программистов. Ибо : понижается читаемость кода за счет не понятной крутости! Если уж программист офигенно крут пусть лучше пофиксит 100500 багов в любом багрекере какого-либо Open-Source проекта

Comment: @sys_dev, если речь идет о программировании на ассемблере и кто-то не понимает, что делает код (кстати, совершенно естественный для обмена регистров)

    xor r1, r2
    xor r2, r1
    xor r1, r2

или аналог на Си


    r1 ^= r2;
    r2 ^= r1;
    r1 ^= r2;

то просто встает вопрос об его профпригодности.

Answer (score 1):

Если значения переменных уже в регистрах, например EAX, ECX тогда команда
xchg eax,ecx

Comment: Ну да, обычно так и делается. Насколько знаю, поменять местами значения переменных в памяти невозможно ни на одной архитектуре, т.к инструкция вида:

MOV <память>,<память>

не поддерживается. Собственно, поэтому значения всегда следует загонять в регистры.

Comment: @xFFh Могу ошибаться за давностию лет, но на pdp-11 вроде проблем не было (кроме длины цепочки в байтах). Три XOR (максимальная длина команды 6 байт) -- и всё (для данных 1-2 байта длиной)

Comment: @alexlz, все точно. 

В pdp-11 (а следовательно и в VAX) и в IBM 360/370 (и т.д.) есть  команды (в т.ч. XOR, ADD и т.п.) память-память.

Comment: @avp пришлось искать, потому как XOR память-память в s/360 я уже не помню. Но есть. Но это совсем не то, что в pdp-11 (там просто системы адресации играют -- процессор-то намного проще). Может кто в курсе, как в MC 68000 -- они вроде pdp-11 брали за образец.